# Using URLs to launch intents - several possible duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

- [How to register some URL namespace (myapp://app.start/) for accessing your program by calling a URL in browser in Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/how-to-register-some-url-namespace-myapp-app-start-for-accessing-your-progra)
- [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android)
- [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)
- [On blackberry and android : calling native application from a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016497/on-blackberry-and-android-calling-native-application-from-a-web-browser)

Should any of these be closed as duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two should definitely be closed as exact duplicates of the third, which has an accepted answer and was the earliest question.

The fourth is a *maybe*, since it also concerns Blackberry apps.